# Como saber si el servidor esta disponible usando Volley?

Tags: android, volley

Estoy usando `volley` para descargar unos datos desde un servidor con `PHP` pero tengo el problema que cuando el servidor no esta disponible `volley` me retorna un error:

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        String message ="";
       String message ="";
                    if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                        message = "Error Network!";
                    } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                        message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
                    } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                        message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
                    } else if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
                    } else if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

He probado de esta forma pero siempre me dice Error network, es decir, el primer if, pero si tengo Internet.

Comment: Igmer recuerda que puedes tener internet , esta disponible pero no es posible establecer conexión, por ejemplo que te encuentres en una red con password vencido o simplemente el proveedor tenga algún tipo de problema, por cierto ¿no olvidaste el permiso internet en tu app verdad?

Comment: funciona bien cuando el servidor esta conectado, por error lo desconecte y me di cuenta que entra en el primer if y en realidad no es un problema del lado de la app sino de disponibilidad del servidor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NetworkError:**

Si entra en este punto:

```
 if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                        message = "Error Network!";
 }
```

indica:

- Que tienes internet disponible pero no conectividad.
- Definitivamente no tienes conexión a internet, ejemplo "modo avión".
- La url no existe.

---

**ServerError**:

Para detectar si el servidor no esta disponible o retorna algún error de la serie 500 (`ServerError`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debería entrar aquí:

```
 } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                        message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
}
```

Comment: El detalle es que desconecte el servidor y siempre entra en  `volleyError instanceof NetworkError`

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si desconectaste el servidor y al cargar la url en el browser muestra "Host not found" o que la página no existe entonces si entrará a NetworkError , en cambio si tienes un verdadero problema con el servidor por ejemplo http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwioLSYdWq?indent=2a entonces entraría a ServerError, por cierto lo comprobé usando un ejemplo que tengo: https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Volley

Comment: ahora entiendo! muchas gracias me has ayudado mucho

Comment: por cierto una mina de oro tus repositorios

Comment: Hey gracias @IgmerRodriguez , me da gusto te ayudo mi información.